# Visual Studio identification for plug-in development purposes?

Tags: visual-studio, plugins

Where does Visual Studio identify its version. E.g. As Express, Standard, Professional, etc?

For example, the Express version does not support extensibility through add-ons. How do add-on authors prevent against their product being integrated with the Express version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do add-on authors prevent against their product being integrated with the Express version?

They don't need to. Microsoft have disabled the functionality that looks for plugins. So even if it gets installed the Express version doesn't go looking.

There may well be hacks you can do to get the Express versions to load plugins, but if that's the case people will probably try to hack your plugin too.

Comment: What about that problem with TestDriven.NET - they were installing their plugin into a version of VS Express at one point no? http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2007/05/30/microsoft-vs-testdriven-net-express.aspx

Comment: @John - Thanks for reminding me about that. From what I remember and re-reading the comments it looks like TestDriven.NET used a hack to get it to work with the Express editions. So if someone's prepared to do that...

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a VSIX plug-in, then see e.g.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/01/19/using-the-vsix-manifest-editor.aspx

The VSIX manifest declares the editions it can be installed into.

Comment: Thanks. That's part of the answer I'm looking for - it covers 2010.  VS2008 is still in wide use, and I'm sure 2005 is relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know the answers to those offhand.  :)  Hopefully someone else will post the answer.